# net-snmp - privacy protocols: which available? which used?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

net-snmp 5.8. supports '-x AES**256**'
How can i find out, if my snmp server supports that?

For trying to use that i get

```
> /opt/netsnmp/bin/snmpwalk  -v3 -l authPriv -u frank -a MD5 -A frank123 -x AES256 -X frank123  127.0.0.1
Timeout: No Response from 127.0.0.1
```

Whereas it works for using -x AES128.

I am using

```
> /opt/netsnmp/bin/snmpwalk --version
NET-SNMP version: 5.8
```

And compiled with AES256 support.
Is it rules on mib file level?
How is the privacy protocol selected a) for a given user or b) an snmp query?
Looking at the tcpdump, i cannot find any **selector** for the privacy protocol.
Is there one in the SNMP protocol?

Comment: "How can i find out, if my snmp server supports that?" The manual of your SNMP server should make it obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The USM MIB https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414 lists the users and their
authentication / privacy for a SNMP agent. Eg.

```
% snmpwalk -v 1 -c public snmp.live.gambitcommunications.com snmpUsmMib
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsUnsupportedSecLevels.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsNotInTimeWindows.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsUnknownUserNames.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsUnknownEngineIDs.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsWrongDigests.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmStatsDecryptionErrors.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmUserSpinLock.0 = INTEGER: 721764
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmUserSecurityName."...I.MIMIC"."user1" = STRING: user1
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmUserSecurityName."...I.MIMIC"."user2" = STRING: user2
...
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmUserAuthProtocol."...I.MIMIC"."user1" = OID: SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmNoAuthProtocol
...
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmUserPrivProtocol."...I.MIMIC"."user1" = OID: SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmNoPrivProtocol
...
```